# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на картинку она менялась местами с другой картинкой

Tags: javascript

[image: То есть вот на место большой картинки станет маленькая в низку большая пойдет на место маленькой и так при любом варианте !]

```html
<div class="monkey-photo">
  <img class="main" src="img/monkey-main.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="first-level">
  <p>Monkey Apes</p>
  <img src="img/one.jpg" alt="" id="one">
  <img src="img/two.jpg" alt="" id="two">
  <img src="img/three.jpg" alt="" id="three">
  <img src="img/four.jpg" alt="" id="four">
  <img src="img/five.jpg" alt="" id="five">
</div>
```

Comment: Опиши точнее или приведи примеры таких "смен местами". Пример у тебя есть. Например нажали на картинку  `img/three.jpg` - с кем она будет меняться местами?

Comment: - Картинка <img src="img/one.jpg" alt="" id="one"> это картинка в низку круглая (первая) 
- при нажатии на неё она становиться на место большой  в class="main" src="img/monkey-main.jpg" и тогда в этом классе уже src="img/one.jpg", а в <img src="img/monkey-main.jpg" alt="" id="one">
- И так если нажму на четвёртую картинку в низу то она станет на место уже  class="main" src="img/one.jpg", а тот src пойдет в низ вместо 4той

Comment: Просто когда нажму на любую картинку внизу (круглую) то она станет на место большой, а большая пойдет на на место той картинку на которую я нажал в низу (круглою)

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что приходит на ум - это подмена адреса изображения.

*<sup>(Просто поразительно, как схож JS-код, который был сохранён гораздо ранее на Codepen в процессе написания ответа, с кодом в предыдущем ответе. Возможно, что это просто совпадение в виду очевидности и оптимальности решения ;-)</sup>*

```js
let largeImage = document.querySelector('.main');
document.querySelector('.first-level').addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  let target = ev.target;
  if (target.tagName != 'IMG') return;
  let temper = target.src;
  target.src = largeImage.src;
  largeImage.src = temper;
})
```

```css
.wrapper{margin:0 auto;display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:center;align-items:center;gap:10px;width:min-content;padding:10px 64px;border-radius:10px;background-color:#30384d}.monkey-photo img{height:256px;width:256px;object-fit:cover}.first-level{display:flex;flex-flow:row nowrap;width:100%}.first-level p{margin:0;color:#fff;flex:1}.first-level img{margin:0 -15px 0 0;height:48px;width:48px;border-radius:50%;object-fit:cover;box-shadow:0 0 3px 1px #30384d}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="monkey-photo">
    <img class="main" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9kuJ.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="first-level">
    <p>Monkey Apes</p>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MraLT.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVNC.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VLC.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG0R.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Если же присмотреться к исходной разметке, то можно заметить, что у изображений присутствуют также дополнительные атрибуты, такие как **alt** и **id**. Переносить каждый из атрибутов по отдельности иррационально, поэтому предлагаю перемещать непосредственно сами элементы `<img>`:

```js
document.querySelector('.first-level').addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  let target = ev.target;
  if (target.tagName != 'IMG') return;
  let largeImage = document.querySelector('.monkey-photo img');
  let parent = largeImage.parentElement;
  target.before(largeImage);
  parent.append(target);
});
```

```css
.wrapper{margin:0 auto;display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:center;align-items:center;gap:10px;width:min-content;padding:10px 64px;border-radius:10px;background-color:#30384d}.monkey-photo img{height:256px;width:256px;object-fit:cover}.first-level{display:flex;flex-flow:row nowrap;width:100%}.first-level p{margin:0;color:#fff;flex:1}.first-level img{margin:0 -15px 0 0;height:48px;width:48px;border-radius:50%;object-fit:cover;box-shadow:0 0 3px 1px #30384d}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="monkey-photo">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9kuJ.jpg" alt="" id="zero">
  </div>
  <div class="first-level">
    <p>Monkey Apes</p>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MraLT.jpg" alt="red wall" id="one">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVNC.jpg" alt="yellow flower" id="two">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VLC.jpg" alt="green forest" id="three">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG0R.jpg" alt="blue rose" id="four">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> когда нажму на любую картинку внизу (круглую) то она станет на место большой, а большая пойдет на на место той картинку на которую я нажал в низу

Как вариант...

```js
document.querySelector('.first-level').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const o = e.target
  if (o.tagName != 'IMG') return
  const ob = document.querySelector('.monkey-photo .main')
  const val = o.src
  o.src = ob.src
  ob.src = val
})
```

```css
.first-level {
  display: flex;
}
.first-level img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="monkey-photo">
  <img class="main" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/i?id=c091ce6918e2ae3de34494d8bbb998d7e43fe3f0-5216463-images-thumbs&n=13" alt="">
</div>

<div class="first-level">
  <p>Monkey Apes</p>
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/i?id=e40e5aaa92fd4de964daa53a016ebeb20190a527-6379389-images-thumbs&n=13" alt="" id="one">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/i?id=b097a424f14742e20c7b3012a25dfdadd0cb002a-7992926-images-thumbs&n=13" alt="" id="two">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/i?id=090dc77181d7bdde5fbafee651d68907ec607c41-8174067-images-thumbs&n=13" alt="" id="three">
</div>
```